# How to create a dynamic choices of model field in django

Tags: python, django

```
class Task(models.Model):

    owner_set=set()
    for each in User.objects.all():
         owner_set.add((each.username,each.username))

    Owner = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=owner_set)
```

In the code, i create a field by the choices of User, but this leads a problem:
When i create a new user, the new username will not apprear in the filed of "Owner";
i need to restart the server. So i want that the Owner filed should be dynamic, is there any way to do this?

I don't want to use the `Owner= models.ForeignKey(User,...)` because may be i will use the names not only from the auth_user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you store Owner as a CharField? If it's a reference to a User object, it should be a ForeignKey.

**Edit after comment** Your data model seems broken. Nevertheless, if you really want to keep it as a CharField, you should not try to set the choices in the model at all. Define a custom form and either use a ModelChoiceField or set the choices in the form's `__init__` method.

Comment: ,Is there any way can implement as my comment, i don't want to use ForeignKey because maybe the choices is not from User